# Drools is very slow in processing big data

Tags: drools, drools-planner

We have integrated Drools with Talend ETL. Drools takes lot of time to process records counting upto half a million or more. How can we increase the processing speed of drools. I am familiar with drools coding but i am not aware how drools  internally works. please help me with this issue. It would be really greatful. I am not sure whether I have given right tags i.e whether they have the right answer. But please do help me on this as it is needed.

Comment: More detail, please. How long is "a lot of time". Is it used for insertion - how much time for n facts? Is it the firing of the rules - again, how much time for how many? How many rules? How complex are they? This is for starters...

Comment: Assuming that the "drools-planner" tag is correct, it would be quite normal for processing to take a while, and you define how long it should spend to provide a reasonable answer. Is this question really about Drools Planner (now called OptaPlanner) or Drools Expert?

Comment: we have used around 30 rules with multiple conditions in it. we are under the assumption that Drools takes one record and compares it against the records then will give the output for each one.So the time taken for processing 1 million record is around 4 hours. Cant we not process the records in batches. I mean to say in big numbers and reducing time for processing.
Pls help me this issue. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

The typical problems involve:

- Not using == constraints, to allow for indexing.

  - Make sure you have the field on the left, and the variable on the right.
- Not having your most restrictive  patterns and constraints first
- Not ensuring your rules are written to avoid large cross products
- Use of multiple accumulates per rule, or sub networks.

  - The last issue is improved in Drools 6.0.